# how to add minus sign value to label?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

Using ArcMap, I've made a map with graduated colours, labeling them with the  same attributes value.

The colours display correctly, but the labels don't show the negative sign.

For example: 
Red area has a value of `-2.769`. It's the lowest, but the label shows it without the negation, So it appears as though it has the highest value (`2.769`).

[image: map]
Edit: I didn't understand where did I do wrong. So I made everything from scratch. Now, it's working.

Comment: That's very strange... how do you handle the labeling? are you using maplex?

Comment: I'm very new at this.  I don't even know what a maplex is. :)  I just clicked Layer properties>labels>selected my column name in label field. and then clicked apply. The graduated colors in symbology is working perfectly so I'm assuming there is nothing wrong with attributes. I couldn't apply the other answer because I don't know any coding.

Comment: I've never experienced that, it seems that there is a problem with the labeling field.

Comment: @gulyuks what your field format? Labeling use string to result. Consequently you can cast value to text in your labelling unicode([Your_Field]) if you are feature is stored in utf-8 (by default since 10.3) or str([Your_Field])  if you are feature is stored iso8859-1 or other system encoding (non unicode)

Answer (score 1):

If you double click on the layer in the layer control, a dialogue will come up with multiple tabs.  Select the labels tab on these properties, Click expression (label expression?), click the advanced check box and set the parser to python

```
def negateLabel ( [attributeName] ):
    attributeVal = int(attributeName)
    if attributeVal  < 0:
        return "- " + [attributeName]
    else:
        return [attributeName]
```

You may have to play around as I don't have ArcMap to hand and the python might be wobbly, but it would be good for you to play around with it, for that's pretty much on the money.

Comment: it says; "The expression contains an error. Modify the expression and try again. Error 0 on line 0. SyntaxError: invalid syntax(<string>, line 1)." I played around little bit but it gives same error.

Comment: Remove the int part if it is coming across as an Int

Comment: Also, make sure your python is correctly indented; each line has to be 4 spaces indented, so after and if, it has to be 8, etc, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this VBScript function. Set the parser to be VBscript instead of Python:

```
Function FindLabel ( [your_field]  )
if ([your_field] < 0) then
FindLabel = "-"+ [your_field]
else
FindLabel = [your_field]
end if
End Function
```

Your field must be numeric. Is your field numeric or text?

Comment: It says "this expression is valid". But still doesn't show negative sign. It's numeric.

Comment: It's numeric. I changed the number format to numeric and added thousand seperator and changed rounding>number of decimal places=0

Comment: what happens if you click with the identify tool on the red polygon? do you get the right attribute?

Comment: Yes. It's -2.769

Comment: Have you tried to open your map in a new project? Could you please verify if you have maplex labeling turned on? Go to Customize -> toolbars -> labeling. Then try to turn on/off use maplex label engine.

Comment: I just did it from scratch. It's working now.